# How to write a put method with @putmapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am learning about spring rest api and wrote a following method to save the data into the database.

```
@GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
        , @RequestParam String email) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
}
```

now i want to write the put query which can take user id and then update the name or email. Also, I need to check that username and email should not be null and also email is in valid format.

How can i construct my method using @putmapping to perform my task.

Comment: there would be many articles for this, did you try to google it?

Comment: http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-mvc-postmapping-getmapping-putmapping-deletemapping/

Comment: i tried but i didnt understand it. well i will try again

Comment: You really should deep-dive into some extensive tutorials. Actually, the only thing that is seems alright in the code snippet is the name of the method. First, you would use POST instead of PUT for adding new users. Second, you can receive the entire user object instead of params. Third, validation is not done in a controller, do it on the entity using BeanValidation or in the service layer. Fourth, your question is not concrete enough, so I'm going to vote to close it. Please don't feel discouraged. Learning building Spring Restful Apps isn't done in a day.

Comment: *"i want to write the put query"* **Hint:** `PUT` is not a *query*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic validations should be done in the mapping class only.

You can refer below example:

Suppose your mapping class and request method will be like:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

 public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
      = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    private String aboutMe;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    // setters and getters 
}

@PutMapping(path="/update")
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it how you are suggesting, but I'd just pass the whole object to be updated:

```
@PutMapping(path="/update")
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "Updated"; }
```

As for null-checking fields and validating email, you could have a validateUserFields function that takes a User object and returns a boolean so you can:

```
if(validateUserFields(user)) 
    userRepository.save(user)
```